When, and in what manner, did horizontal writing in East Asian languages switch from right-to-left to left-to-right?
East Asian languages (Chinese, Japanese, and Vietnamese) imported the Western style of horizontal writing as contact with the West increased, but it was always still written in the traditional direction of right-to-left. It is my understanding that prior to and during WWII, the right-to-left direction was still firmly cemented as the norm for horizontal writing.
However, today, horizontal writing in East Asian languages is almost always conducted in the Western left-to-right style. My question is, when exactly did this process happen, and how? The geographic distribution of these languages was wide and under areas controlled by numerous different governments and cultures, yet the shift to left-to-right horizontal writing seemingly occurred homogeneously. How late into history was the right-to-left horizontal style still used? This picture (below) of the 1964 Singapore race riots shows both the use of left-to-right and right-to-left writing directions for horizontal Chinese script.


Please document prior research

For those of us  who can't read Chinese characters, are you saying the second line on these boards goes left to right on some and right to left on the others?

I'd say the first (from left) is left to right, quite sure the second is right to left.

You still see right-to-left writing e.g. on ships and aircraft. Example

East Asian languages go from right-to-left in columns. Characters are read downwards along the right-most column, then the next column would be the column immediately to the left. You should treat horizontal writing from right-to-left as a special case of this, where each column only contains one character. I don't recall any cases where right-to-left East Asian writing spanned more than one row.

@Jan -  your China Southern Airlines example is an approximation of front-to-back: you will see right-to left on the starboard side and left-to-right on the port side of the same plane, and you may see something similar on flags or banners.

@Henry Yes. It is reasonably common on sucb occasions.

Wikipedia doesn't support the idea that horizontal right to left was ever really dominant, just occasional as it still is today. Without evidence to the contrary I vote to close.

However, today, horizontal writing in East Asian languages is always conducted in the Western left-to-right style. This is false as Jan's example shows. // Also, vertical right to left still exists e.g. in Japanese manga (and their Chinese translations).

@user103496 Vertical right-to-left isn't just in Japanese manga, it's in virtually all Japanese and Taiwanese literature (barring things like magazines and certain types of guidebooks). Most Korean newspapers still had vertical right-to-left until December 1997, with Chosun Ilbo retaining it into 1998. My question was never about vertical writing, but purely horizontal writing. I do admit my wording was imprecise with "always" and have edited it accordingly.

Hopefully it didn't happen suddenly mid-sentence, otherwise that line would have been unreadable.

@LittleWhole Repeating earlier comments, you haven't provided any sources that support your assumption of a historical switch. We cannot explain a phenomenon that doesn't exist.

@BrianZ right-to-left writing is common in horizontal Chinese writing before roughly (in my experience) the 1950s and is still used in situations where a traditional style of writing is desired. Here are some examples.

@WIJama If you think you have sufficient evidence to demonstrate a historical switch at that time you should edit your question to lay the argument out. Don't make people dig through comments and piece it together.

@BrianZ it's not my question and it's been a while since I read about this topic, but I'll try to put together an answer when I get the time (probably in a couple weeks). if anyone else is interested in pre-empting me and doing the research themselves, iirc for Chinese it's related to PRC language policies, and for Japanese it's related to modernization in the Meiji period. I don't remember what the answer is for Korean.
